# PropertyWrapper cannot make wrappedValue initialization infer

Tags: swift

I am using this custom PropertyWrapper, if I set max and min value it makes an issue and Xcode complain `Missing argument for parameter 'wrappedValue' in call`

```
@propertyWrapper struct ValueCheck<T> where T: Numeric & Comparable {
    
    var minValue: T
    var maxValue: T
    var wrappedValue: T {
        didSet(oldValue) {

            if (oldValue != wrappedValue) {
                if (wrappedValue < minValue) { wrappedValue = minValue }
                else if (wrappedValue > maxValue) { wrappedValue = maxValue }
            }
  
        }
    }

    init(minValue: T, maxValue: T, wrappedValue: T) {
        
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue

        if (wrappedValue >= minValue) && (wrappedValue <= maxValue) {
            
            self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
            
        }
        else {
            
            if (wrappedValue < minValue) { self.wrappedValue = minValue }
            else { self.wrappedValue = maxValue }
            
        }
    }
  
}
```

use case:

```
struct CustomType {

  @ValueCheck(minValue: 0, maxValue: 100) var value: Double

}
```

Error:

`Missing argument for parameter 'wrappedValue' in call`

My Goal is that I be able to do down code in struct:

```
@ValueCheck(minValue: 0, maxValue: 100) var value: Double
```

Comment: The error is reported because your (only) initializer has 3 arguments: `minValue`, `maxValue`, and `wrappedValue`

Comment: Why not create an init that takes only minValue and maxValue as arguments or supply a default value in your current init?

Comment: Are you hoping to supply the initial value of `value` in `CustomType`'s initialiser? Do you realise that `value` is not required to be initialised in `CustomType`'s initialiser in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It maybe useful to look at what a property wrapper functionally translates to.

```
struct Foo {
    @ValueCheck(minValue: 0, maxValue: 100) var value: Double
}
```

is basically:

```
struct Foo {
    private var _value = ValueCheck<Double>(minValue: 0, maxValue: 100)
    var value: Double {
        get { _value.wrappedValue }
        set { _value.wrappedValue = newValue }
    }
}
```

Notice that all stored properties are initialised, and you are not required to initialise any of them in the initialisers of your struct. Assuming the `ValueCheck` initialiser call were valid, this code should compile without any initialisers. But that's not right - what would I get if I tried to access `Foo.value` without ever setting it?

```
Foo().value
```

If you are willing to accept that what you are doing is unsafe, you can just cheat by using an optional in your property wrapper. Notice the precondition.

```
@propertyWrapper struct ValueCheck<T> where T: Numeric & Comparable {
    
    var minValue: T
    var maxValue: T
    private var wrappedOptional: T? = nil
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            precondition(wrappedOptional != nil, "No wrapped value set before first access!")
            return wrappedOptional!
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if newValue < minValue {
                wrappedOptional = minValue
            } else if newValue > maxValue {
                wrappedOptional = maxValue
            } else {
                wrappedOptional = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    init(wrappedValue: T? = nil, minValue: T, maxValue: T) {
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue

        guard let wrappedValue = wrappedValue else {
            return
        }

        if (wrappedValue >= minValue) && (wrappedValue <= maxValue) {
            self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        }
        else {
            if wrappedValue < minValue {
                self.wrappedValue = minValue
            } else {
                self.wrappedValue = maxValue
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

*You* would need to make sure that you initialise things marked with `ValueChecked`, because the Swift compiler will not check it for you.

Alternatively, if you don't want to be unsafe, you can also do this:

```
struct CustomType {

    @ValueCheck
    var value: Double
    
    init(value: Double) {
        self._value = ValueCheck(minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, wrappedValue: value)
    }

}
```

By not passing the arguments immediately after `ValueCheck`, the `_value` property is uninitialised. You can then initialise it in the initialiser.

Comment: I really do not believe it is because of my codes that does not works! I see my issue as a bug of PropertyWrapper! My original code in my question would  be working just fine if I had this code: `init(minValue: T = 0, maxValue: T = 100, wrappedValue: T) {...)` then without dealing with optional like you did, my code would infer the wrappedValue! So what I asked or did in my question to doing this:  `@ValueCheck(minValue: 0, maxValue: 100) var value: Double` that means Xcode need to infer the `wrappedValue`! which the bug happens there.

Comment: I can show some working code that simply shows other bug of PropertyWrapper, I believe there so unclear code or situations with PropertyWrapper. plus your given code would never can execute the codes in initialization after reach guard! So all your codes after guard is really never used! You could draw picture or say jokes after guard or fatal error! It can not proceed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240634/discussion-between-sweeper-and-swiftpunk).